# How to change the associated GitHub repository after publishing a module to deno.land/x/?

Tags: deno, github-webhook

I decided to migrate to a new github repo (not just changing the repo name) for a published deno module but cannot find a way to do it.

The [manual](https://deno.land/manual@main/publishing) says:

> Module versions are persistent and immutable. It is thus not possible
> to edit or delete a module (or version), to prevent breaking programs
> that rely on this module. Modules may be removed if there is a legal
> reason to do so (for example copyright infringement).

Does that mean the repository info is permanent and immutable too? I tried to use the same Webhook link in my new repository, but when I publish a new version, I noticed it didn't successfully trigger the update on deno.land/x/. The Webhook response is:

```
{"success":false,"error":"module name is registered to a different repository"}
```

Is it possible to change the associated GitHub repository link for a published deno module? And if so, how to?

Comment: Do you just want to rename the GitHub repository, or do you also want to change the name of the module on deno.land/x? If you change the repo name and create a new tag with the existing webhook, it should publish a new version to the existing module on /x. If you want to associate a module on /x with a different repo, I believe you need to contact the Deno team about that.

Comment: @Zwiers I want to use a different repo. I actually wanted to split my repos into two modules, and soon I realized you can't use the same repo for two different modules. But I have already pointed the new module at my old repo. Now the repo has two associated modules, both having the same content. If I rename it, the other module will be affected too.

Comment: Best thing to do probably is to go on the Deno Discord or GitHub and ask there, I'm not sure it is possible to change the github repository for an existing module on /x.

Comment: According to the registry policy, It is not possible without a legally-compelled reason. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72746678/438273

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in case any future persons are curious. Luca Casonato (a deno core team member) clarified that you are just able to send an email:

> Yes, send an email to modules@deno.com

Hope that helps!